# Rewrite Conditions in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ex-ex[/]*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subsite/ex [R=permanent,L,NE]
```

I am redirecting `mysite.com/ex-ex` to `mysite.com/subsite/ex`

This is working fine, but `mysite.com/ex-ex/page1` redirects to `mysite.com/subsite/ex`. How can I redirect to `mysite.com/subsite/ex/page1`?

How can I append the remaining part of url also to new url pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^/ex-ex(.*)$ /subsite/ex$1 [R=permanent,L,NE]
```

**Edit:** added a slash in the Rule

Comment: hey its working needed to make some changes , thanks , but one more Q plz help , what should be done if url has more than 1 parameter like page1/test/example

Comment: It should work for that case too. (.*) grabs everything after ex-ex, and appends it to /subsite/ex.